# Implementing invisible bones

Tags: directx9

I suddenly have the feeling that I have absolutely no idea how to implement invisible objects/bones.

Right now, I use hardware instancing to store the world matrix of every bone in a vertex buffer, and then send them all to the pipeline. But when dealing with frustum culling, or having them set to invisible by my simulation for other reasons, means that some of them will be randomly invisible.

Does this mean I effectively need to re-fill the buffer from scratch every frame with only the visible unit's matrices? This seems to me like it would involve a lot of wasted bandwidth.

Comment: Chills from the first sentence...

Comment: @Byte56 This question best read by flashlight at a campfire.

Comment: Thanks for the funny comments, but I was hoping to, y'know, get some useful input on the problem.

Comment: Why not simply do both?

Comment: OK, how are you setting them to be invisible? And why would having bones be invisible require you fill the visible units matrices from scratch?

Comment: @Byte56: Because the invisible units and the visible units all share the same instance buffer. So unless I want to issue 99999999 Draw calls to draw only the visible ones, the only solution I can see is to re-fill the instance buffer each frame, which I'm putting in the "wasteful" category of ideas.

Comment: @Byte56: The question is how to set them invisible. Right now, the outside world can request invisibility by flipping a bit. I'm just not sure how to efficiently fill that request.

Comment: So, you want units to have missing limbs, or be invisible entirely? Couldn't you just make them reference an global "invisible" bone instead of the regular visible bone? The global invisible bone just being one with zero scale.

Comment: @Byte56: That would still entail vertex shading them, amongst other processing.

Comment: Well I don't think you're going to get it for free. Try one, or both, then worry about performance.

Comment: "Right now, I use hardware instancing to store the world matrix of every bone in a vertex buffer, and then send them all to the pipeline." I don't understand this sentence. Are you doing matrix palette skinning, or are you just rendering a bunch of the same object in different places? Because the latter doesn't involve *bones* at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I'm doing both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well put this as an answer... I'd try implementing what I suggested and have units or objects that you want to be invisible reference a bone with zero scale. Really that's only for units that have multiple bones and you want to just make part of it invisible. Otherwise, just remove the position offset or change it to really far away when you want to make a unit invisible. Try letting the graphics card sort out what to draw.

You can't worry too much about performance yet. At least try these things out before disregarding them as to costly. Premature optimization and all that.